# Why do phase I [vaccine] trials [normally] last several months if [on average] they can't find any serious adverse effects?

Tags: vaccination, clinical-study

Let me ask a "devils' advocate" question that hopefully clarifies a point on another popular (for some reason) question here:

We can read [for example](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/26350571/) (in a meta-analysis that's not even specific to vaccines but was done across all types of medications; actually 26.1% of these were for vaccines [n=124]) that

> Data on adverse events and trial characteristics were extracted from all phase I trials published in PubMed, Embase, Cochrane, Scopus, and PsycINFO (1 January 2008 through 1 October 2012). [...]
>
> In 475 [Phase I] trials enrolling 27,185 participants, there was a **median of zero serious adverse events (interquartile range, 0-0) and a median of zero severe adverse events (interquartile range, 0-0) per 1000 treatment group participants/day of monitoring.** The rate of mild and moderate adverse events was a median of 1147.19 per 1000 participants (interquartile range, 651.52 – 1730.9) and 46.07 per 1000 participants/AE monitoring day (interquartile range, 17.80 – 77.19).

Why are these Phase I trials even conducted if they can't find any truly serious safety problems?
According to [healthline](https://www.healthline.com/health/clinical-trial-phases), Phase I trials [normally] last several months. Are they a waste of time? Why not start with a larger sample?

Comment: The term `regulatory capture` is used when `a special interest is prioritized over the general interests of the public, leading to a net loss for society`. Many scientists and doctors believe that this phenomenon corrupted institutions responsible for safety of pharmaceuticals and also many medical journals. A former employee of a institutions responsible for medical safety analysis reported that early warning signs were disregarded and even that a study they started was doctored to ensure that no safety signal will be found.

Comment: In [out to see](https://youtu.be/ZmErXFRKAOo) Dr. [John P.A. Ioannidis](https://profiles.stanford.edu/john-ioannidis) makes polite and very restraint comments about regulatory capture. I assume that JPA is either not aware or not willing to [acknowledge the harms of any mRNA injection](https://doctors4covidethics.org/gene-based-vaccination-quo-vadis/): `each and every mRNA-“vaccine” will incite self-destructive processes in lymphatic organs and in blood vessels throughout the body.` My assumption is [based on his remark on pushback - is it worthwile ~49m](https://youtu.be/ZmErXFRKAOo?t=2957)